# Truncating Strings In JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a string placed inside the  tag and I wanted to truncate it and add an ellipsis at the end of the truncated string. I coded this using jquery and it seems my code doesn't work on my end.

here is my jquery code:

```
$(".link-content > h4").each(function(){
    var len=$(this).text().lenght;
    var str=$(this).text().substr(0,26);

    var lastIndexOf=str.lastIndexOf();

    if(len>26){
        $(this).text(str.substring(0, lastIndexOf)+"...");
    }
});
<div class="links">
    <span>FACEBOOK</span>
    <div class="link-content">
         <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
           Etiam lacus tellus, tristique congue pellentesque ac, semper eu 
           d iam.</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: To start with, `.lenght;` won't work

Comment: so how do we get the lenght of the string? @CertainPerformance

Comment: `length`, not `lenght`

Comment: my bad. had a little typo. thank you though.. @ThumChoonTat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract the original text into a variable, and if its length is greater than 26, set the text to that original text with `slice(0, 26)` called on it, and concatenated with `...`:

```js
$(".link-content > h4").each(function(){
    const origText = $(this).text();
    if (origText.length > 26) {
        $(this).text(origText.slice(0, 26) + '...');
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="links">
    <span>FACEBOOK</span>
    <div class="link-content">
         <h4>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. 
           Etiam lacus tellus, tristique congue pellentesque ac, semper eu 
           d iam.</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's some example code of how to quickly truncate and add '...' for any string that was truncated.  There is a one that will truncate (big) and one that will not (small).  I think you seem to have the rest of it down.

```
var big = '1234567890123456789012345678901234567890';
var small = '1234567890';
var big_truncated = big.substr(0,26);
var small_truncated = small.substr(0,26);

big_truncated += (big.length > 26)?'...':'';
small_truncated += (small.length > 26)?'...':'';

console.log(big_truncated);
console.log(small_truncated);
```